# Remove unwanted bar in histogram

Tags: r

I have the code below to produce the histogram attached. For some reason, there is a random black bar in the bottom and top left corner. I tried removing by setting the x limits to 0 and 5. The bar is not present if "annotation_logticks()" is not added. How can I remove this unwanted bin?

Also as a side note, what is the best way to move the log ticks to the outside? adding "outside = TRUE" does not work.

[image]

```
gg <- ggplot(c, aes(x = b.GRN.B.HLin, after_stat(count))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = nbin, binwidth = bw, fill = "white", color = "white") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::math_format(10^.x), limits = c(0, 5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), expand = c(0,0)) + geom_density(aes(y = bw *..count..)) +
  annotation_logticks()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reprex would be helpful to provide an answer to unwanted bar.  We don't know what is your dataframe `c`.  Perhaps you can post a small sample dataframe.  To add logticks to the outside, modify your `annotation_logticks()` as `annotation_logticks(short=unit(-1,"mm"), mid=unit(-2,"mm"), long=unit(-3,"mm"))`

Comment: The bar ended up being because I never specified "sides" as bottom only, so they were the log ticks on the left. I added "coord_cartesian(clip='off')" along with what you suggested and it worked :). Thanks!